# Can we render post chat survey form to user(Agent) once chat window is closed instead of Customer?

Tags: liveagent

I have a requirement on salesforce live agent that instead of showing post chat survey form to customer, we need to display the form to agent and agent will complete the survey. Please guide me whether it is feasible or not.

Answer (score 0):

We can use onChatEnded() method to display an feedback edit page to the agent in event handler.